# Shell command to remove a folder contents recursively excluding hidden files?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I want to remove a folder contents and it's sub-folder contents without removing hidden files in folder and sub-folders. How can i do it by using shell script??

I have tried `rm -rf foldername` but it is removing entire contents.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `-exec` or `xargs`, you can just do:

```
find folder_name -not -name ".*" -delete
```

- This removes all files and folders that do not start with `.` (hidden files/folders)
- This removes folders if and only if they are empty (so it won't remove folders containing hidden files, as required)

Answer (score 2):

That's a tricky one.  An outline solution might be:

```
find foldername -type f ! -name '.*' -exec rm -f {} +
find foldername -type d -depth -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
```

The first command removes files with a name not starting with `.`; the second tries to remove directories.  The `-depth` option means remove sub-directories before removing directories.  The `+` notation is from POSIX 2008 [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) but works fine on Mac OS X (10.7.5, anyway).  The `2>/dev/null` sends any 'directory not empty' error messages (and, indeed, all others) to oblivion.

You might run into issues with symlinks, Unix sockets, FIFOs, and other non-files; tweak the first command to suit your requirements.  If you use `!` for history, you might need to escape that.

Answer (score 1):

by passing an argument `-name "*"` to the `find` command will leave by default all the hidden files.so you can use the below command.

```
  find . -name "*"|xargs rm -f
```

Comment: The `rm -fr` means that any directories will be forcibly removed along with all their contents, hidden and non-hidden.  Using just `rm -f` would get rid of files and other non-directories.  To remove empty directories, you need `rmdir`.  (Using `-name "*"` is clever, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command:

```
find foldername/ -type f -not -name '.*' | xargs rm -f
```

The find command finds all files under foldername/ whose names don't start with a '.' (hidden file),  and passes them to xargs,  which runs rm -f on them.